# Spinner Value not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am running into some trouble with my spinners. When every I select a value from them the spinner only takes the first value in the list.

For example I have a spinner with vales 1,2,3,4,5. When I select 4 the value taken from the spinner 1, this is the same if I select any of the other values.

Am I implementing the Spinner wrong? Or taking the values from the spinner wrong?

**Spinner**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/heatSpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/heat_title"
    android:entries="@array/heat"/>
```

**Array/Heat**

```
    <string-array name="heat">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
```

**Taking Values from Spinner**

```
                Spinner heat = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.heatSpinner);
            final String heatValue = heat.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final int finalHeat = Integer.parseInt(heatValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I dunno if this way is the best way to do it but it worked for me.

You need to set a `setOnItemSelectedListener` for each spinner, inside this you will be then able to set the value of your variable to the items of the spinner.

So your spinner might look something like this, again this may not be the nicest looking approach but it worked for me anyway, hope it helps

```
                final Spinner heat = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.heatSpinner);
            heat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    final String heatValue = heat.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    int finalHeat = Integer.parseInt(heatValue);
                    db1.updateHeat(finalHeat, recipe_number);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // your code here
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the 4º block of code in your question.

Are you sure that

```
int servingSize = servings.getInt(0);
```

Is getting the value that you want?

And in

```
seekBar.setProgress(size);
```

what is this 'size' parameter? Are you sure that you are passing the right value to the setProgress() method? I didn't see this 'size' variable in your code.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question, i found out that the spinner itself wasnt actually working and the values that i was trying to get from the spinner werent being passed to the variables